# Sink strainer rotates to stopper position when water is running

Tags: drain, sink, kitchen-sink

I have a standard kitchen sink strainer/stopper, like in the images below.

When water is running, it frequently rotates to the stopper position, in the direction of the current around the drain.

There’s nothing about the design that I can see that would prevent it from closing with a little rotational force.

Is there any clean way to solve this? I don’t want to damage anything in a misguided attempt.

[image: Sink strainer]
[image: Sink strainer inner part]

Comment: Just seems like a bad, untested design. Take the strainer into a plumbing or hardware store and find a matching one. They are not that expensive. If you cant find one, then you may have to change the outlet in the sink.

Comment: I mean, if you never use the stopper function why not just glue it in place?

Answer (score 3):

There are two simple options.

1. Buy a strainer basket that doesn't act as a stopper. Example:[image]
2. Buy a different style strainer basket that doesn't rotate and has a plunger to stop the water from draining. Example:
   [image]

You can easily find these styles by shopping for "sink strainer basket".

This is likely caused by either the strainer not being sized correctly for the drain center or one/both of them are worn and allow rotation. The cheapest and easiest option is to simply but a different style strainer.

Comment: Getting a strainer that actually works with a particular sink is a matter of trial and error, as there appears to be no standard design. Last time I needed a strainer, I had to buy 4 different ones before I got one that worked with my sink.

Comment: Get the kind that's just a bent strip of metal on the bottom. Spread it a little, and then it's difficult to put into stopper mode. Or just stop using them altogether... How else are you going to use a fork to make it work like a garbage disposal?

Comment: I tried the stopper version of the first option (also Oxo), but it drained so slowly that the sink would fill up when the water was on. I can give the second a try.

Comment: @NaftaliBeder The first option is not a stopper at all; it is a separate strainer. I personally, have two different ones: a strainer and a stopper, but that is because I have a garbage disposal and am too cheap to replace the two that I already have with a single pop-up style.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Oh yeah I was saying I tried a similar Oxo product that acts as both strainer and stopper :)